# Find matching between two text files in Terminal

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal

I have a big .txt file with 1,755,972 lines (one value/line). I have another .txt file that has 1,400 line (one value/line). I want to see the matching between the two regardless of the order between the two lists.

Any suggestions?

input1.txt

```
rs1
rs2
...
rsn
```

input2.txt

```
rs10
rs8
rs1
...
rsn
```

Comment: Well, basically do `sort` of the two file, `uniq` if necessary, then `diff`.

Comment: … then `diff` or `comm`, whichever fits you better. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the following `grep -xvFf file2.txt file1.txt` and `grep -xvFf file1.txt file2.txt`. I also tried `comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`. I tried too `sort file1 file2 | uniq -u`. BUT, I don't think any gave me the output i want (which is I need a list of the common lines between the two files regardless on the order they are in in the two files). THANK YOU in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the lines common to two text files, regardless of their order in the files, do this :

```
sort file1.txt > sorted1.txt
sort file2.txt > sorted2.txt
comm -12 sorted1.txt sorted2.txt
```

Use `sort -u` if you wish to only compare unique lines.